# How to use nested dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#

My requirement is

```
Dictionary<outerString, Dictionary<innerString, List<SelectListItem>>>
```

When I try to get the value of the inner Dictionary using key(outerString), it gives an error saying "cannot apply indexing with type of expression...............".

I have tried this

```
Dictionary<outerString, Dictionary<innerString, List<SelectListItem>>> dict1 = new
    Dictionary<outerString, Dictionary<innerString, List<SelectListItem>>>;

Dictionary<innerString, List<SelectListItem>> dict2 = dict1.values["outerString"];
```

Any quick help will be greatly appreciated.

Thx in advance.

Comment: `Dictionary<outerString, Dictionary<innerString, List<SelectListItem>>>`, Good Lord!!!

Comment: This is definitely a good place to use `var`.

Comment: what is innerString and outerString ?

Comment: You probably just want to write String instead of outerString and innerString. Note that you have to provide *types* rather than variables in a type signature.

Comment: You might want to introduce a class or two to encapsulate that data structure. Nested generics is just manual code obfuscation!

Comment: Are `innerString` and `outerString` types? It's common practice to capitalize the first letter of a class/struct name.

Answer (score 6):

I guess what you need is just:

```
Dictionary<innerString, List<SelectListItem>> dict = dict1["someKey"];
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to change the last line of your code snippet to (I assumed where you wrote inner string and outer string you must meant string):

```
var dict = dict1["someValue"];
```

Additionally, you could probably make your code much readable with the var keyword:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<SelectListItem>>>();
var dict = dict1["someValue"];
```

Answer (score 2):

So `outerString` and `innerString` are *types*? Did you actually just want a nested dictionary `string` -> `string` -> `List<SelectListItem>` ? If not, you'll have to show us the definition of these types, and give the compiler some way to convert from the **`string`** you are trying to index with...

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```
Dictionary<outerString, Dictionary<innerString, List<SelectListItem>>> dict1 = new 
Dictionary<outerString, Dictionary<innerString, List<SelectListItem>>>(); 

// Get inner dictionary whose key is "someValue"
Dictionary<innerString, List<SelectListItem>> dict = dict1["someValue"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Did I misunderstand you? This works fine

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> list = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
list.Add("test", new Dictionary<string, List<string>>());
Dictionary<string, List<string>> inner = list["test"];
```

or

```
var list = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
list.Add("test", new Dictionary<string, List<string>>());
Dictionary<string, List<string>> inner = list["test"];
```

Comment: Thx astander & others for quick reply
I was doing list.values["test"];
But, the need was 
list["test"];

Answer (score 0):

In

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<T>> dict1 = 
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<T>>();
```

you need

```
List<T> list12 = dict1["key1"]["key2"];
```

---

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
list1.Add(1);
list1.Add(2);

Dictionary<string, List<int>> innerDict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
innerDict.Add("inner", list1);

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<int>>> dict1 =
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<int>>>();
dict1.Add("outer", innerDict);

List<int> list2 = dict1["outer"]["inner"];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you use an array of strings for a key, rather than trying to nest the dictionaries -

```
       Dictionary<string[], List<string>> dict = 
           new Dictionary<string[],List<string>>();

       string[] key = {"inner", "outer"};
       List<string> vals = new List<string>();

       dict.Add(key, vals);
```

Comment: Dictionary relies on the semantics of the Equals and GetHashCode methods. Neither of which are implemented on arrays. In other words:


var x = new string[] { "one", "two" };


var y = new string[] { "one", "two" };


Console.WriteLine("x == y? {0}", x.Equals(y));


Outputs:


x == y? False